# Foreign key constraint prevents insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, ssms

I would like to set up a table, add the foreign key and then add the data into the table but it is not allowing me to do that.

My two test tables are as follows

```
CREATE TABLE tesa 
(
    company_id INT UNIQUE,
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    last_name VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE testb 
(
    company_id INT UNIQUE,
    company_code VARCHAR(3),
    policy_no INT
)
```

The first entries for the test tables respectively

```
tesa (1, dan, fitz) 
testb (1, abc, 2)
```

These were entered through SQL Server Management Studio's "Edit Top 200 Rows" command. They were accepted fine.

I then added the foreign key using

```
ALTER TABLE tesa 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_tesa_testb_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES testb (company_id)
```

This was also accepted fine.

The issue I run into is when I add the foreign key and then attempt to add additional entries, even clearing and re entering the two entries that were accepted I get an error message saying that there was an issue with foreign key constraint. I tried this on another system and it accepts all the information fine, not sure what this issue would be.

Comment: Please show the error message verbatim.

Comment: Hi Dale, thank you apologies i thought the screen shot of the error had uploaded with the question

Comment: We don't want screenshots anyway... just the test... verbatim.

Comment: Will do thanks again

Answer (score 0):

With the foreign key in place, you know must **ensure** that an entry in `testb` exists with a valid `company_id`, before you can insert something into `tesa`.

So for the two inserts you showed, you must run the

```
INSERT INTO testb (company_id, company_code, policy_no) 
VALUES (1, 'abc', 2)
```

**first**, so that the entry in `testb` with `company_id = 1` exists, before you can run this:

```
INSERT INTO tesa (company_id, first_name, last_name)
VALUES (1, 'dan', 'fitz')
```

Otherwise, that FK constraint **will perform its duty** and tell you that you cannot insert a row into `tesa` if a row with that same `company_id` doesn't exist in `testb` beforehand.

Also, allow me to voice an observation: the way it is set up right now, you can **only** ever have **one entry** in `tesa` for a given `company_id`, since that value must be `UNIQUE` - is that really your intent? Seems like if those were e.g. customers or employees of a company, you'd want to have possibly *multiple* entries for any given  `company_id` in `tesa`, referencing that one company (a **one-to-many** relationship). Just wondering ....

And another point: neither of your tables defines a **primary key** - which is typically one of the mainstays of referential integrity. Your current setup *does work*, because SQL Server allows allows a table to reference a **unique constraint** in another table - but you should really think about what the **primary key** of both your tables should be.

And lastly: **please** use more expressive names than `tesa` and `testb` for your tables.... `testb` should most likely be called `Company`, and for `tesa`, use whatever makes sense - `Customer`, `Employee`, `Fan` - whatever these people are to the company they're connected to .....

Comment: Thank you I followed the sequence entering values into 'testb' first and then into 'tesa' I understand now why the issue occurred. I will certainly format future questions as you have indicated , feedback is much appreciated.